# c# serialport datareceived handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

When SerialPort receives the data, I need to know custom parameter. Custom parameter I know when I make SerialPort. There are several open ports simultaneously. 
I need to know which port calls DataRecieved and his custom parameter.

Number of serial ports is dynamic (stored in an array - not shown below).

Custom parameter should be an object but can also be a string. For each serial port one custom parameter. 2 ports = 2 customparams.

```
private void Start()
{
    SerialPort _serialport1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    _serialport1.Type = "Analyzer 1"; // custom parameter ?
    _serialport1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandle (SerialPort_DataReceived, "Analyzer 1");
    _serialport1.Open();

    SerialPort _serialport2 = new SerialPort("COM2", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    _serialport2.Type = "Analyzer 2"; // custom parameter ?
    _serialport2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandle (SerialPort_DataReceived, "Analyzer 2");
    _serialport2.Open();
}

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, object e)
{
    string _type = (string)e;

    if(_type == "Analyzer 1")
    {
        // Do something
    }

    if(_type == "Analyzer 2")
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Should I create a custom handler? Or custom class of SerialPort with custom parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final code that I used:

```
public class SerialPortA : SerialPort
{
   public string DeviceType { get; set; }

   public SerialPortA(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits, string deviceType)
       : this()
   {
       //...
   }
   //...
}

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if ((sender as SerialPortA).DeviceType == "Analyzer 1")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't control what is passed to the event handler, because the event is raised by the `SerialPort` object itself. The second parameter will *always* be an instance of `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs`, and you can't change that.

However, you can always check the `sender` parameter to see which `SerialPort` object raised the event:

```
private SerialPort _serialport1;
private SerialPort _serialport2;

private void Start()
{
    _serialport1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    _serialport1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandle (SerialPort_DataReceived, "User Object 1");
    _serialport1.Open();

    _serialport2 = new SerialPort("COM2", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    _serialport2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandle (SerialPort_DataReceived, "User Object 2");
    _serialport2.Open();
}

private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, object e)
{
    string s = null;
    if (sender == _serialPort1)
    {
        s = "User Object 1";
    }
    else if (sender == _serialPort2)
    {
        s = "User Object 1";
    }
    ...
}
```

As a side note: local variable names shouldn't start with an underscore; that convention is normally reserved for fields (i.e. member variables). Just use `camelCase` for local variables.